# Why is Xlib's Display.record_create_context() method not suggested by Visual Studio Code's code completion feature?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, xlib

I am trying to understand interface interactions in Python. To start off, I have tried to deconstruct a simple mouse-cursor-hiding program found here:
https://github.com/eazar001/mousetrap

Here is the relevant bit of code:

```
from Xlib import X, display
from Xlib.ext import record
from Xlib.protocol import rq

record_dpy = display.Display()

ctx = record_dpy.record_create_context(
        0,
        [record.AllClients],
        [{
                'core_requests': (0, 0),
                'core_replies': (0, 0),
                'ext_requests': (0, 0, 0, 0),
                'ext_replies': (0, 0, 0, 0),
                'delivered_events': (0, 0),
                'device_events': (X.KeyPress, X.MotionNotify),
                'errors': (0, 0),
                'client_started': False,
                'client_died': False,
        }])
```

I noticed that Visual Studio Code doesn't seem to think the method record_create_context exists (at least it doesn't show up in the code completion suggestions, nor am I able to find it in the Locals and Globals while debugging).

I got everything to run, but I am still bugged by the question of where this method is implemented, and why it doesn't show up in the suggestions.

I searched Google for record_create_context, and was hoping for some documentation. I didn't find any, just some programming examples.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added code, sorry about that

Comment: Here's the [document](https://python-xlib.github.io/python-xlib_15.html#Display) about Xlib.display.Display(). But it doesn't include `record_create_context`.

Comment: Exactly! There is this undocumented function with not even any metadata that VS Code can extract, but still it's there, and usable. Still some people have figured out the way to use it (by copying and pasting the same bit of code I find in all the examples). Where does this knowledge come from, and how can the function be implemented, yet invisible? My goal is to learn something here, but it seems I'm reduced to just copy & paste, with no avenue to understanding